# Need to upload 6tb data file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using storage gateway as my second source of real-time backup to S3. The issue is the data is around 6tb. I would like to know can I upload 6tb data to S3. I know that 5tb is the limit. But do we've any way to fulfill the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size **of a single object** is 5TB.

If you are copying multiple files, you will be fine. It will just take a while!

Comment: how can this be fulfilled? can you share the steps

Comment: Are you saying that your backup is a single file that is 6TB in size? Or does your backup consist of multiple files? Where are you obtaining the 5TB size limit (please link)?